# Does 1Password Have API Access to Secrets?

Tags: .net, 1password

While using Azure Key Vault, we follow the workflow below. Our .NET app:

1. Has Key Vault client id and secret set in the ENV. These are the ONLY env vars it has other than [ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0#environments).
2. Authenticates to Key Vault using the above.
3. Fetches all the secrets it needs for the current env on startup.
4. Sets the secrets either in either the ENV or configs to be available for runtime.

Is the same workflow possible with 1Password? I am not seeing any APIs or .NET SDKs, but still wanted to check for solutions I could be missing.

My goal is to have the app have a minimum number of env vars preset and fetch everything it needs from a secret manager. I hate having to hand developers `.env` files for different environments and have it break all the time because a new secret was added or changed. With the approach above, Azure Key Vault is the single source of truth. Unfortunately, we have to switch to 1password now.

It seems the closest I can get is the [1password CLI](https://developer.1password.com/docs/cli/secrets-scripts/), no API / .NET SDK. Not sure if it will do the job yet, but it seems to from a quick glance.